# How to center items in a bootstrap column such that every item starts in the same position relative to the X axis?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, flexbox

In order to replicate my problem, I wrote a simple HTML with 2 bootstrap columns, I would like my second column to have multiple `<p>` items , each one of them below the other, however the issue arises when the strings contained in the `<p>` tag are of different lengths, since I want them to be in the center of the column but to also start in the same position relative to the X-axis.

```
<body>
<h2 class="text-center my-5">
    title
</h2>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 ">
            Some unrelated text
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-6">
            <p>Small text</p>

            <p>A much longer text</p>

        </div>

    </div>

</div>
```

Essentially I would like the string "A much longer text" to be exactly below "Small text", so that it would look this way:

```
Small text
A much longer text
```

Instead of

```
   Small text
A much longer text
```

I tried styling the column with text-align:center as well as using flexbox and align-items:center but they both produce the same result.

Comment: I am assuming this is only for `sm` and below, when the `<p>`s are stacked. In that case, you still want the thing to be center and start with equal left space, OR (this might look better), start everything from the left? (Just talking about the small screen)

Comment: I am not fully seeing how two unformatted `<p>` elements are behaving differently from each other. Do you have any CSS which is affecting `p:first-child` or anything similar? The answer might be to remove some formatting that is affecting that first paragraph.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first you need to add a `d-flex justify-content-center` classes to your column then add a `div` parent to your `p` tag so your code will be like that

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 ">
            Some unrelated text
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-6 d-flex justify-content-center">
            <div>
            <p>Small text</p>

            <p>A much longer text</p>
            </div>


        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for, thanks

Answer (score 1):

Using the bootstrap 4 `flex` box should solve the issue. On running the code below, you would find that bootstrap responsiveness is placing the `col-md-6` in 2 lines. Running code outside stack overflow should give the result you desire.

> Edit: Added some javascript code to center the text as per the comments from the OP

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
    let divLeft = $('#div-center-text').position().left;
    
    let min = 0;
    $('.center-text').each(function(i, obj) {
      let p = $(obj);
      let pLeft = p.position().left;
      if (min==0 || min>pLeft)
        min = pLeft;
    });
    
    $('.center-text').each(function(i, obj) {
      $(obj).offset({left: divLeft + min});
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>

      <head>
        <title></title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://pro.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.10.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-AYmEC3Yw5cVb3ZcuHtOA93w35dYTsvhLPVnYs9eStHfGJvOvKxVfELGroGkvsg+p" crossorigin="anonymous" />
      </head>

      <body>
        <h2 class="text-center my-5">
          title
        </h2>
        <div class="container">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6 border">
              Some unrelated text
            </div>
            <!-- .col-md-6 -->
            <div class="col-md-6 border" id="div-center-text">
              <div class="d-flex flex-column align-items-center w-100">
                <p class="mb-0 center-text">Small text</p>
                <p class="mb-0 center-text">A much longer text</p>
              </div>
              <!-- .flex-column -->
            </div>
            <!-- .col-md-6 -->
          </div>
          <!-- .row -->
        </div>
        <!-- .container -->
      </body>
    </html>
```

[image]

Comment: Maybe I didn't explain myself correctly . I want the first character of "A much longer text" to be exactly below the first character of "Small text". As seen on your image and the code provided , "A much longer text" starts a few px at the left compared to "Small text". Additionally I want both strings to be centered (that is correct in your code)

Comment: @JoseDelgado Added some JS code to center the text as per the requirement. Currently `A much longer text` is centered and the `Small text` is aligned to it. To make `Small text` centered and other one align, change condition of `min` to `max`

Answer (score 0):

Using bootstrap reslove your issue, you can align content in center ofthe page horizontal.
try below example.

```html
<div class="pricing4 bg-light" style="margin-top: -20px;padding-bottom: 25px;margin-bottom: -32px;">
<div class="container">
    <!-- Row  -->
    <h2 style="text-align: center;padding: 40px;">This is improper content (div)</h2>
    <div class="row justify-content-md-center">
        <!-- Row  -->
        <div class="row justify-content-md-center" style="margin-left: 30px;margin-right: 30px;">
            <!-- Column -->
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <div class="card card-shadow border-0 mb-4">
                    <img class="card-img-top" src="https://i.ibb.co/GFrTmrm/dummy-size.jpg" alt="wrappixel kit">
                    <div class="pveventcard">Tuesday 11th May, 6:00PM</div>
                    <div class="p-3" style="height: 200px;">
                        <h6 class="font-weight-medium mb-0">The event is going bla</h6>
                        <h6 class="subtitle font-13">16/5/2021</h6>
                        <p>short description goes here short </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- Column -->
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <div class="card card-shadow border-0 mb-4">
                    <img class="card-img-top" src="https://i.ibb.co/GFrTmrm/dummy-size.jpg" alt="wrappixel kit">
                    <div class="pveventcard">Tuesday 11th May, 6:00PM</div>
                    <div class="p-3" style="height: 200px;">
                        <h6 class="font-weight-medium mb-0">The event is going bla</h6>
                        <h6 class="subtitle font-13">16/5/2021</h6>
                        <p>short description goes here short </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- Column -->
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <div class="card card-shadow border-0 mb-4">
                    <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
            <iframe class="embed-responsive-item" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/YE7VzlLtp-4"></iframe>
        </div>
                    <div class="pveventcard">Tuesday 11th May, 6:00PM</div>
                    <div class="p-3" style="height: 200px;">
                        <h6 class="font-weight-medium mb-0">The event is going bla</h6>
                        <h6 class="subtitle font-13">16/5/2021</h6>
                        <p>short description goes here short </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```